# Записать многомерный числовой массив в файл, а затем зачитывать его по частям

Tags: python, list

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как записать многомерный список в файл, а затем читать его по частям. При этом, нужно получать именно массив, а не текстовую строчку. Поясню на примере, который похож на мою задачу.
Есть список:

```
a = []
a.append([1,2,3,4,5])
a.append([11,12,13,14,15])
a.append([21,22,23,24,25]) # Таких строчек будет 30000

b = [10,20,30,40,50]

c = (a,b) # Таких строчек будет 1000000

print(c) # Здесь print(), а нужна запись в файл.
$([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

Хочется в цикле (for i in (1000000):) записывать такой картеж(или массив - не принципиально), как "с" в файл. Затем нужно будет читать из этого файла строчку с нужным номером. При этом, принципиально важно получить именно список с числами, который потом будет обрабатываться, как список.
Например:

```
z = файл[номер строчки из файла = с[i]] [0] # Получаем объект типа list
h = файл[номер строчки из файла = с[i]] [1] # Получаем объект типа list
```

Как это можно сделать с наименьшими потерями в производительности?

Comment: Я ответ обновил. Подходит?

Comment: Написал Вам коммент к вашему ответу. Подходит, но немного по-другому :) Через eval() и repr(). Хотел Вам поставить плюс за ответ, но я пока не могу плюсовать сообщения - рейтинга у меня не достаточно. Так что пока на словах, спасибо!

Comment: Планируете ли вы работать с массивами размерности > 3? В вашем примере - будут ли все строки `c` одинаковой формы (например: (3x5), 5)?

Comment: Да, у меня будет список на 1000000 строчек, таких, как 'c'. Каждая строчка 'c' будет состоять из 'a' и 'b'. 'a' будет размером (30000x5), а 'b' будет размером (1x25).  Да, все 'c' будут одинаковой формы. Но я уже почти решил использовать, то, что предлагает @vadim vaduxa. Только я попробую сделать не 1000000 отдельных файлов, а запихнуть в каждый файл хотя бы строчек по 7000, таких, как 'c', чтобы в память влезали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) читать данные из файла - дорогостоящая по времени операция, по этому лучше читать все в переменную и работать уже с ней.

2) если объем данных не позволяет держать их в памяти, то помещать все данные в один файл, тоже плохая идея.
    Например, при чтении сотой строки файла, необходимо предварительно считать предыдущие 99 строк.
     Те при каждом обращении к файлу будет считыватся "лишняя" информация(строки с меньшими индексами)

3) чтобы избежать излишнего считывания(как в п2) и не держать данные в памяти(как в п1),
можно, например, данные помещать в разные файлы, а не в разные строки одного файла.
    Для этой цели воспользоватся [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html)
    + класс `DataFile`, который обеспечивает функционал чтения и записи в файл с конкретным индексом.
Чтобы к DataFile можно было обратится с помощью оператора `[]` нужно определить методы
    [`__setitem__`](http://pythonz.net/references/named/object.__setitem__/)
 [`__getitem__`](http://pythonz.net/references/named/object.__getitem__/)

```
import pickle

class DataFile:
    def __setitem__(self, index: int, value):
        '''сохранить в файл index.data'''
        with open('{}.data'.format(index), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(value, f)

    def __getitem__(self, index: int):
        '''читать из файла index.data'''
        with open('{}.data'.format(index), 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = DataFile()
    # записать в файл file[индекс] - индекс.data
    file[0] = [[2, 1, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
    file[1] = 10
    file[2] = {'123': [-1, -2, [-3]]}
    # читать из file[индекс] - индекс.data
    d1 = file[0][1][-1]  # 15
    d2 = file[1]  # 10
    d3 = file[2]['123'][2]  # [-3]
    print(d1, d2, d3)
```

Comment: Похоже, то что нужно, но хочу разобраться в Вашем коде. Пока не до конца понимаю, что это за класс DataFile. Я в программировании новичок и до конца с классами не разобрался пока. DataFile - это какой-то встроенный класс или это может быть любое имя? Как DataFile понимает нужно ему читать или писать в файл? Вы тут как-то переопределяете встроенные методы __setitem__ и __getitem__? И заодно хочу спросить про "if __name__ == '__main__':" . Я много где это встречал, но не понимаю зачем это делается. Ведь без этой строчки всё равно будет работать, мы вызываем классы и так в основном теле программы

Comment: 1) DataFile обычный пользовательский класс
2) чтобы к любому классу можно было обратится(как к списку/словарю) с помощью квадратных скобочек, необходимо задать методы `__getitem__` чтение, и `__setitem__` присвоение.
В методы передается индекс, `DataFile[1] -> DataFile.__getitem__(1)`
 происходит чтение из файла с именем `'{}.data'.format(индекс)`, те  файл `1.data`, с записью аналогично.
3) блок кода, заключенный в `if __name__ == '__main__'` выполнится только для главного файла, который мы запустили, для файлов, которые мы импортировали код выполнен не будет

Comment: 1) Спасибо, понял 2) Т.е. какой метод использовать __getitem__ или __setitem__ определяется тем, что мы будем делать с этим классом? Т.е. если мы пишем DataFile[1] = 10 () (т.е. присваиваем значение 10), то будет использован метод  __setitem__ , а если пишем d2 = DataFile[1] (т.е. получаем из класса значение), то будет использован метод  __getitem__ ? Круто :) 3) Код который мы импортировали - это имеется в виду import pickle и т.д.? Т.е. если там вдруг имеется класс DataFile(), или переменная file, то мы их не затронем?

Comment: Хотя, в общем, вроде бы разобрался - здорово! Сейчас попробую потестировать на своем примере, похоже, что так и сделаю, как Вы предлагаете. Спасибо! Отпишусь по результатам.

Comment: ТО ЧТО НУЖНО!!! Отличная идея, спасибо большое! Сделал один-в-один, как Вы предложили! Плюсанл бы Ваше сообщение, но у меня рейтинг только 9, а чтобы плюсовать нужен 15. Спасибо Вам лично, а также всем, кто пытался мне помочь! Тему закрываю, мой вопрос решён полностью. Всё круто!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу можно решить, приведя список с строке:

```
temp_lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
global_lst = []

for i in range(4):
    global_lst.append(temp_lst)

f = open('test.txt', 'a') #атрибут a - будет открывать файл на дозапись, w - на перезапись
f.write(str(global_lst))
f.close()
```

Также подойдёт использование функции repr():

```
f.write(repr(global_lst))
```

Чтобы работать с файлами, нужно их открыть. Если файл не существует, он будет создан (только если файл открыт не на чтение). Сделать это можно двумя способами:

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'attr') # где attr - формат работы с файлом (r, w, a, r+, w+, rb, wb)
```

Такой формат работы с файлом автоматически не закрывает его, поэтому после работы с ним, его нужно закрыть:

```
f.close()
```

А такой формат работы автоматически закрывает файлы и позволяет открывать несколько файлов сразу:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file1.txt', 'a') as f2:
    data = f1.read()
    f2.write(data)

try:
    f1.read()
except:
    print('file closed')
```

Получить потом индексацию, конечно, будет невозможно. Да и, вообще, лучше для работы с данными использовать специализированные библиотеки типа pandas и формат данных типа csv или json. Но если так хочется работать с базовыми инструментами, то могу предложить такой вариант на запись:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a') #атрибут a - будет открывать файл на дозапись, w - на перезапись
for x in range(len(global_lst)):
    for j in range(len(global_lst[x])):
        f.write(str(global_lst[x][j]) + ' ' + str(x) + ' ' + str(j) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Таким образом, на каждой новой строке мы запишем:

```
число первый_индекс второй_индекс
```

Потом, подавая строки на ввод, мы можем восстановить исходный массив, применяя к ним функцию split(' ') и получая из каждой строки массив вида:

```
[число, первый индекс, второй индекс]
```

Ну а далее уже дело за малым: верно собрать массив, обращаясь к элементам массива каждой строки.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за наводку на repr(). Погуглив на тему repr() я ещё нашел функцию eval(). Попробовал - вроде бы задача моя решена :) Ураа!!! Чуть позже приведу код, который мне помог. Сейчас его ещё немного потестирую и выложу.

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков договор)

Comment: не получается нормально редактировать код. Наверное лучше в новом сообщении напишу

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков правильно я понимаю, что вы хотите записать массив в файл 'somename.py', чтобы потом запустить скрипт?

Comment: Ну да всё верно, правда не обязательно в *.py. Я формирую массив X (на это уходит где-то час). В оперативку он не влезает - проверенно :) Затем мне нужно его обработать другой частью программы. Мне нужно случайным образом выбирать из него все строчки. Выбираю, например случайно 10000 строчек, обрабатываю, затем снова и т.д. К тому же, хочется сохранить массив X, чтобы каждый раз его не формировать (долго). Просто 2ю часть проги, которая обрабатывает X нужно ещё отлаживать, экспериментировать с ней и.п.

Comment: Похоже нужно присмотреться к pandas, как Вы и советовали. Просто стандартными средствами python не могу придумать, как выдирать из X любую строчку (случайно), либо нужно чтобы выдернуть 1 строчку пробегаться по всему огромному массиву - это похоже очень долго получится :) Нужна возможность обращаться к строчке по индексу....

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков я вам дал новый ответ

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков плюс я не совсем понимаю что вы хотите сделать. Рандомно взять индекс? Импортируйте модуль random. Также можно записывать данные в json формате. Для этого можно импортировать модуль json. Изучите документацию

Comment: Рандомно взять индекс - не сложно. У меня не получается зачитать строчку с этим рандомным номером из файла. Про json я начал копать ещё до того, как задал вопрос здесь. Там тоже стандартный метод load() - загружает весь файл в память, как я понял, а он у меня туда не влезет. Мне нужно, чтобы можно было выбирать строчку по индексу. Скорее всего pandas мне поможет - буду копать в эту сторону.

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков ваш массив - одна строка. А pandas также будет загружать всё в память, как и json, как и eval(). Вы просто хотите сделать глупость и ищите для этой глупости глупое решение

Comment: Я уже частично накопал вроде бы - pd.HDFStore. Если это не поможет, то буду пробовать копать в сторону базы данных на MySQL. Когда решу проблему - напишу, как сделал.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Записываем файл
outputfile = "./DATA/test_file.txt"
myfile = open(outputfile, mode='w', encoding='latin_1')
myfile.write(repr(c)) # repr()
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.write(repr(c)) # repr()
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.close()

# Читаем из него
myfile = open(outputfile, mode='r', encoding='latin_1')
a1=[]
a2=[]
for line in myfile:
    g = eval(line) # eval() - очень крутая штука :)
    a1.append(g[0])
    a2.append(g[1])
print(a1)
$[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]]
print(a2)
$[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]
```

И всё бы было хорошо, если бы не проблема с зачиткой из файла. Ломаю голову, как зачитать не все строчки подряд, а только с нужным номером. Т.е. нужно набрать новый массив из строчек с определёнными номерами. Строчки идут не по порядку... Так что ещё думаю. Вопрос пока решен не полностью :(

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях код выглядит не очень, так что напишу в ответе.

Тут мы создаём многомерный массив:

```
temp_lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
temp_lst2 = []
global_lst = []

for i in range(4):
    temp_lst2.append(temp_lst)

for i in range(4):
    global_lst.append(temp_lst2)
```

Тут мы его записываем в файл:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(global_lst) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Тут мы читаем многомерный массив из файла и выводим некоторые значения:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
lst = eval(f.readlines()[0]) # задаём переменной lst первую строку из файла 'test.txt'
print(lst[0]) #[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
print(lst[0][0]) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(lst[0][0][2]) # 3
```

P.S. Познакомьтесь с индексацией

**UPD**

Последний апдейт и последний ответ. Если в файле лежат массивы, которые нужно собрать в многомерный, это можно сделать так:

```
global_lst = []

file = open('filename.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    lst = eval(line) # берём строчку и преобразуем её в массив
    global_lst.append(lst) # и добавляем этот массив в глобальный массив
```

А так можно преобразовать сколькоугодномерный массив в одномерный (это так, на всякий и на будущее):

```
temp_value = global_lst[0]

while type(temp_value) == list:
    global_lst = [item for sublists in global_lst for item in sublists]
    temp_value = global_lst[0]
```

Comment: lst = eval(f.readlines()[0]) - было бы очень здорово и полностью бы решило мою проблему, НО как только я запихиваю этот f.readlines()[i] в цикл, сразу получается ошибка "out of range", хотя вручную всё вроде бы работает. Пробовал я сегодня так. Первая строчка цикла отрабатывает, а на второй выдается ошибка.

Comment: myfile = open(outputfile, mode='r', encoding='latin_1') # читаем
a1=[] # Обнуляем
a2=[] # Обнуляем
for i in range(0,2): # так выдает ошибку. for i in range(1,2) - работает
    g = eval(myfile.readlines()[i]) # берём строчку
    a1.append(g[0]) # заполняем a1
    a2.append(g[1]) # заполняем a2
print(len(a1)) # Проверяем сколько строчек зачитано

Comment: А зачем readlines() запускать цикле? readlines() для того, чтобы прочитать строки. По ним уже цикл нужно пускать

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков ```lst = eval(f.readlines()[0])``` это весь твой список сразу. По файлу не надо проходиться циклом, чтобы прочитать твой массив. Ты его записал в одну строку По крайней мере, если ты его писал так, как я. Я сделал readlines()[0], а не read(), потому что мало ли ты записывал что-то помимо самого массива в текстовый файл. В любом случае твой массив расположен на первой строчке

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков если ты хочешь прочитать часть массива из текстового файла, так это нереально. Реально, конечно, но нужно верно подбирать индексы, потому что в файле находится строка, а не массив.

Comment: @ПётрКолтаков а если у тебя массив разбит на 2 массива и ты хочешь из них собрать крупный, то я сейчас обновлю ответ. Смотри после UPD

Comment: Мне не это надо. Собрать из нескольких массивов один методом .appen() у меня и не вызывало сложности. Преобразовывать записанный в виде строчки список обратно в массив Вы мне подсказали как- eval(), спасибо большое, но у меня осталась не решена другая проблема. Мне ещё нужно из текстового файла выдергивать именно ту строчку, которая мне нужна, не зачитывая весь текстовый файл целиком. Скорее всего мне нужна индексация внутри моего текстового файла, как в базах данных. т.е. , например, выдернуть строчку номер 103, а затем уже её преобразовывать в объект список.

Comment: Тему не закрою, пока не решу свою проблему. Буду ещё гуглить. Когда решу, могу запостить своё решение. Всё равно спасибо Вам большое за помощь и за потраченное на меня время.