# Создание многомерного массива из файла

Tags: python, массивы

Только недавно в пайтоне и компактность многих операций довольно значительно усложняет изучение языка.

Так вот, есть в файле четырехмерный массив [3x10x40x1000], разделенный пробелами. Все значения безраздельно идут через пробел одной строкой за исключением последнего измерения (его размер 1000): после него начинается новая строка.

Как восстановить из этого потока чисел исходный массив?

Пример:

Вход:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

Выход: 
[((1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9)),((11,12,13)(14,15,16)(17,18,19))((21,22,23)(24,25,26)(27,28,29))]

```
Bas=[[[[]]]]
for i in range(1,1000): 
    for j in range (1,3): 
        for k in range (1,10): 
            for z in range (1,40): 
                total=+1
                Bas[[i],[j],[k],[z]]=array[total]
```

array- одномерный массив с данными из текста

И вот такая ошибка во время работы:

```
    Bas[[i],[j],[k],[z]]=array[total]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: Файл-таки плоский. Максимум в него 2 измерения влезает без ухищрений. Приведите пример входных данных и желаемый результат. Тысячами не нужно, хватит пятерки-десятка элементов в по каждому измерению.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: вместо `Bas[[i],[j],[k],[z]]` должно быть `Bas[i][j][k][z]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я полностью согласен с @Arnial - NumPy пожалуй наиболее оптимально подходит для подобных манипуляций

Я бы хотел немного уточнить [ответ от @Arnial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652486/211923) и дополнить его примером:

Исходный файл (`'C:\Temp\a.txt'`):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

Решение - 3D матрица формы (3 x 3 x 3):

```
import numpy as np
```

numpy.array, dtype: float64:

```
In [25]: np.loadtxt(r'C:\Temp\a.txt').reshape(3,3,3)
Out[25]:
array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.]],

       [[ 11.,  12.,  13.],
        [ 14.,  15.,  16.],
        [ 17.,  18.,  19.]],

       [[ 21.,  22.,  23.],
        [ 24.,  25.,  26.],
        [ 27.,  28.,  29.]]])
```

numpy.array, dtype: int32:

```
In [26]: np.loadtxt(r'C:\Temp\a.txt').reshape(3,3,3).astype(int)
Out[26]:
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16],
        [17, 18, 19]],

       [[21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29]]])
```

"Vanilla" Python, nested list of integers

```
In [27]: np.loadtxt(r'C:\Temp\a.txt').reshape(3,3,3).astype(int).tolist()
Out[27]:
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
 [[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]],
 [[21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29]]]
```

Comment: Да, с numpy все уложилсь в пару строк и заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, какой именно результат вам нужен, но код ниже удовлетворяет вашему примеру.

```
def f(raw):
    lines = raw.split("\n")
    nums = []
    for line in lines:
        l = []
        n = [int(x) for x in line.split(" ")]
        for i in range(int(len(n)/3)):
            l.append([])
            for i2 in range(3):
                l[-1].append(n[i*3+i2])
            l[-1] = tuple(l[-1])
        nums.append(tuple(l))
    return nums

inp = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19\n21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29"
outp = f(inp)
print(outp)
```

Выход:

```
[((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)), ((11, 12, 13), (14, 15, 16), (17, 18, 19)), ((21, 22, 23), (24, 25, 26), (27, 28, 29))]
```

Comment: Какого типа должны быть входные данные? При считывании через Read выдает ошибку на второй строке: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Обычный `str`, как в переменной `inp`. У любого `str` должен быть метод `split()`. Можно вот так: `file = open("file.txt","r"); f(file.read())`, должно работать

Answer (score 1):

Просто для справки. В numpy есть готовая функция для этого

```
import numpy as np
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dim_np_arr = np.reshape(arr, (2,3,2)) # создаст матрицу размерности 2x3x2
#dim_np_arr будет выглядеть так:
#array([[['1', '2'],
#        ['3', '4'],
#        ['5', '6']],
#
#       [['7', '8'],
#        ['9', '10'],
#        ['11', '12']]], 

# чтобы превратить ещё в python массив нужно вызвать .tolist()
dim_arr = dim_np_arr.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Преподоложим у нас в файле test.txt записан многомерный массив. Прочитать его можно таким образом:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
lst = eval(f.readlines()[0]) # задаём переменной lst первую строку из файла 'test.txt'
print(lst[0]) #[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
print(lst[0][0]) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(lst[0][0][2]) # 3
```

Также ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста с [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/649559/243273).

[Этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649787/243273) (тот же, что и тут, но более подробный) подойдёт, если у вы не страдаете от недостатка памяти.

А [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649928/243273) более сложный в понимании и реализации, но более интересен: